# How to apply Continuous Integration for Google Pay

Tags: continuous-integration, backend, google-play-developer-api, google-pay

Background: we actually implemented a google subscription within our mobile-app, plus an API call to regularly check the status of payments as well for Real Time later on.

We have a server side cron-job that will analyze the subscription information and expires them in our database as not PREMIUM anymore if the info was changed.

Fyi: Basically we have a mobile and web app that has central database. This thing is a backend side concern.

In our code we have a mock data for unit testing only, as well we have a huge functional testing with payment modules we have. Our problem right now, there is no way to trigger a one-time/subscription purchase via API in Google Pay API, such endpoint does not exist based on their api docs.

How do you guys handle this kind of scenario, and we want this thing to be part of our CI/CD to avoid breaking changes in the future.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you referring to Google Pay or Google Play here?